# Primary Emails not Being seen as primary

Tags: contacts, email, import

I have an a bunch of organizations we imported via csv. The email addresses are checked under the contacts summary as 'primary'. However they are not receiving emails and reminders and in search results no email is showing. If I go into the record and click on the email section and then click 'save' the email is then seen as primary.

I am wondering if there is a way to fix this in bulk. It's not that many records (approximately 200-300). Any suggestions would be great.

CiviCRM 4.7.27 with WordPress 4.9.5

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this using the 'Update Multiple Contacts' feature. Here are the details:

- I created a profile to be used for search views that contained the Org name and Email (main).
- From search results I selected the Org that the primary email was not showing and selected 'Update Multiple Contacts' from the action menu.
- I  selected my newly created profile for updating email.
- When the update screen loaded I just hit the update button and this updated the main emails to be primary.

Since this was a relatively small amount of records this solution was manageable. Probably not the best solution for a larger amount of records.

Comment: Can you accept your own answer to help close this?

Comment: @petednz, It won't let me accept my answer for 2 days...

Comment: This worked on a civicrm 5.10.3 install.